# Realizing Morse functions on orientable surfaces as height functions.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be an orientable compact surface and let $f : \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Morse function.  Let $h : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the standard height function.  Is there an embedding $i : \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^3$ so that $h \circ e = f$.

I am asking how this works for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I would be interested to know any general results.

Comment: If you don't care about the dimension of the space you're embedding in to then this is easy: if $\phi$ is any embedding of $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb R^n$ then $x \mapsto (\phi(x),f(x))$ is an embedding of $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $f$ is the restriction of the vertical coordinate. With the condition that the embedding must be into $\mathbb R^3$, I don't know the answer offhand. Some googling turns up the article *Realization of smooth functions on surfaces as height functions* by Kudryavtseva, which seems relevant.